# How do I create series in Excel using criteria from values in other cells?

Tags: excel, charts

I have an Excel spreadsheet populated as below:

| Latitude | Longitude | Altitude | Value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 10 | 10 | 1 | 100 |
| 10 | 10 | 5 | 105 |
| 10 | 10 | 20 | 120 |
| 10 | 5 | 1 | 150 |
| 10 | 5 | 5 | 155 |
| 10 | 5 | 20 | 170 |
| 15 | 10 | 1 | 500 |
| 15 | 10 | 5 | 505 |
| 15 | 10 | 20 | 520 |
| 15 | 5 | 1 | 550 |
| 15 | 5 | 5 | 555 |
| 15 | 5 | 20 | 570 |

Using this data, I would like to create a Chart in Excel where I have Value on the X-axis, Altitude on the Y-Axis and a series for each unique combination of Latitude and Longitude.

This should result in 4 series being plotted on the Chart with each series having 3 values (one value for each Altitude. I feel like this should be easy to do but I'm struggling to do it myself or find something using the grand-old Google.

Any help you could provide this Excel-noob would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Thanks for the edit, I'm not sure what I did wrong - the table formatting looked good in the preview...

Comment: Yes, I noticed that too. I simply inserted a newline.

Answer (score 0):

If you re-arrange your data like that

| value | altitude | value | altitude | value | altitude | value | altitude |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| long-lat: | 10-10 |  | 10-5 |  | 15-10 |  | 15-5 |
| 100 | 1 | 150 | 1 | 500 | 1 | 550 | 1 |
| 105 | 5 | 155 | 5 | 505 | 5 | 555 | 5 |
| 120 | 20 | 170 | 20 | 520 | 20 | 570 | 20 |

you can insert the four curves individually into a "points (x/y)" diagram:

[image]

Here is a screenshot of how the curves are defined:
[image]

Comment: Thanks, so you're not aware of any way to do this through a formula? The spreadsheet I have is significantly larger (there are 60 permutations of values that I want to create series for).

Comment: If you are prepared to use a macro then you can certainly achieve the same result with your original table layout (without moving any cells).